# cout printing in reverse order

Tags: c++, function-call, function-object

Trying overloading operator() in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fib {
  public:
    Fib() : a0_(1), a1_(1) {}
    int operator()();
  private:
    int a0_, a1_;
};
int Fib::operator()() {
    int temp = a0_;
    a0_ = a1_;
    a1_ = temp + a0_;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    Fib fib;

    cout << fib() <<"," << fib() << "," << fib() << "," << fib() << "," << fib() << "," << fib() << endl;
}
```

It prints the fib sequence in the reverse order as 8,5,3,2,1,1. I understand the states are kept in () overlading but why the printing is showing up in the reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

operator << is a some function defined for its parameters. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. They can be evaluated right to left or left to right. It seems your compiler evaluates them right to left.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.I was using g++ on cygwin and bsd.

Comment: @KKG10 You should split this one output statement into several statements.

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct. In my mind it should translate to ostream.operator<<(param1).operator<<(param2)...., therefore it should not only generate just 1 function call but multiples? Unless operator<< is somehow different

Comment: @eucristian How are the function calls fib()  evaluated in this line from left to right or from right to left before the C++ 17? The question demonstrates you the answer.